# Django duplicate admin prefix in url

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-admin

I'm running Django in Fastcgi Mode

```
./manage.py runfcgi method=threaded host=127.0.0.1 port=8080
```

with Nginx

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myhostname.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sample_project.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/sample_project.error.log;

    location /static/ { # STATIC_URL
        alias /home/www/myhostname.com/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ { # MEDIA_URL
        alias /home/www/myhostname/static/; # MEDIA_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
       include fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}
```

The admin url is

```
http://myhostname.com/admin/
```

I notice that every HTML link generated is wrong like this one below

```
 ...
 <a href="/admin/admin/logout/">Log out</a>
 ...
```

Below my url.py

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

    from django.contrib import admin
    admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'configuratore.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     )
```

It seems that Django is duplicating admin URL but i'm not understanding why.

Comment: Did you do something weird in your `settings.py`? (say defined your own `LOGIN_URL` or something similar?)

Comment: No, i didn't. The error was in the Nginx configuration file. See Accepted Answer Below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to add `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME "";` to your `location /` block in nginx configuration. By default django prepends it's value to reversed urls, thus setting to empty url should make it work.